# botocore.exceptions.DataNotFoundError when packaging it and running

Tags: pyspark, makefile, boto3, aws-secrets-manager

Obtaining `botocore.exceptions.DataNotFoundError: Unable to load data for: endpoints` when I package my project and run as a pyspark application.
Besides, when I directly run from python I don't get the issue of loading my secrets.

```
  File "/private/var/folders/zn/nr4dngtd7r9046m_s7578mjh0000gq/T/spark-c7582b6a-8b35-47ec-9054-94549db0a963/userFiles-6ba5a3da-ead8-4c9a-83fb-276f3ba5749b/packages.zip/utils/secret_mgr.py", line 11, in get_secret
  File "/private/var/folders/zn/nr4dngtd7r9046m_s7578mjh0000gq/T/spark-c7582b6a-8b35-47ec-9054-94549db0a963/userFiles-6ba5a3da-ead8-4c9a-83fb-276f3ba5749b/packages.zip/boto3/session.py", line 299, in client
  File "/private/var/folders/zn/nr4dngtd7r9046m_s7578mjh0000gq/T/spark-c7582b6a-8b35-47ec-9054-94549db0a963/userFiles-6ba5a3da-ead8-4c9a-83fb-276f3ba5749b/packages.zip/botocore/session.py", line 953, in create_client
  File "/private/var/folders/zn/nr4dngtd7r9046m_s7578mjh0000gq/T/spark-c7582b6a-8b35-47ec-9054-94549db0a963/userFiles-6ba5a3da-ead8-4c9a-83fb-276f3ba5749b/packages.zip/botocore/session.py", line 812, in _get_internal_component
  File "/private/var/folders/zn/nr4dngtd7r9046m_s7578mjh0000gq/T/spark-c7582b6a-8b35-47ec-9054-94549db0a963/userFiles-6ba5a3da-ead8-4c9a-83fb-276f3ba5749b/packages.zip/botocore/session.py", line 1108, in get_component
  File "/private/var/folders/zn/nr4dngtd7r9046m_s7578mjh0000gq/T/spark-c7582b6a-8b35-47ec-9054-94549db0a963/userFiles-6ba5a3da-ead8-4c9a-83fb-276f3ba5749b/packages.zip/botocore/session.py", line 199, in create_default_resolver
  File "/private/var/folders/zn/nr4dngtd7r9046m_s7578mjh0000gq/T/spark-c7582b6a-8b35-47ec-9054-94549db0a963/userFiles-6ba5a3da-ead8-4c9a-83fb-276f3ba5749b/packages.zip/botocore/loaders.py", line 142, in _wrapper
  File "/private/var/folders/zn/nr4dngtd7r9046m_s7578mjh0000gq/T/spark-c7582b6a-8b35-47ec-9054-94549db0a963/userFiles-6ba5a3da-ead8-4c9a-83fb-276f3ba5749b/packages.zip/botocore/loaders.py", line 453, in load_data_with_path
```

** Code to extract secrets from AWS Secret manager **

```
# import botocore
# import botocore.session
import boto3
from aws_secretsmanager_caching import SecretCache, SecretCacheConfig


def get_secret(secret_name: str):
    # client = botocore.session.get_session().create_client("secretsmanager")

    session = boto3.Session(profile_name='default')
    client = session.client('secretsmanager', region_name="ap-southeast-2")
    cache_config = SecretCacheConfig()
    cache = SecretCache(config=cache_config, client=client)
    secret = cache.get_secret_string(secret_name)
    return secret
```

Referred this template to package and deploy: https://pyspark-tdd-template.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html#deploying-into-production
but botocore is creating problems when I run something like this:

```
spark-submit \
--jars dev/hadoop-aws-3.3.3.jar,dev/aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.12.397.jar \
--py-files packages.zip \
--files configs/ \
exec/job_submitter.py --job dl_etl --workflow w.json --project-config configs/project_var.json --job-args name=ba env=dev
```

These are the dependencies

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.9"
pyspark = "3.3.1"
importlib = "^1.0.4"
Jinja2 = "^3.1.2"
black = "^23.3.0"
aws-secretsmanager-caching = "^1.1.1"
botocore = "^1.29.134"
boto3 = "^1.26.134"
```